# Knockout.js error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: myData is not defined; Bindings value: with: myData

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I'm getting the following error, although the script IS working correctly...

> Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: myData is not
>   defined; Bindings value: with: myData

HTML:

```
<table class="w100p table" data-bind="with: myData">
   <tr>
      <td class="col-xs-7" ><span class=" value" data-bind="text: Email"></span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  

    function viewModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.myData = ko.observable();

        function MyViewModel(myData)
        {
            this.Email = myData.Email;
            // etc.
        }

        function billingAddressViewModel(billingAddress) 
        {
            this.Street = billingAddress.Street;
            // etc.
        }

        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            self.myData(new MyViewModel(data));
            self.billingAddress(new billingAddressViewModel(data.BillingAddress));
            }
        });

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

As mentioned, this works fine, data from WebAPI is being shown on the page, but this error remains and messes with the rest of my Javascript code. Any tips on what to improve to red rid of that error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it like this

```
with:$root.myData
```

Also make sure about the spell as javascript is case sensitive language

Comment: changing it to data-bind="with: $root.myData" makes the whole form disappear unfortunately...

Comment: you need to display your complete html code so we can see where problem exists